# Wicket form: disable submit button

Tags: wicket, forms, wicket-1.6, wicket-6

In Wicket when I disable a `Form` instance it perfectly disables my input fields, but it fails to disable the submit button, too.

How to disable the submit button, too, preferable without the need to add `wicket:id` for the submit button?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `wicket:id`?

Comment: Because I then have to use it for every form. I'd rather want it to work automatically - I rather consider it a bug in Wicket, that it does not disable it automatically.

Comment: Disabling the form disables all child _components_ as well.  But without `wicket:id` a Wicket `Component` can never be created for the submit button, it just stays plain HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `AjaxSubmitLink` and add it to the form.  It will be enabled/disabled along with the form:

HTML:

```
<button wicket:id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Java:

```
form.add(new AjaxSubmitLink("submit"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by automatically created `Buttons`. In my `WebApplication`'s `init()`-method I install an `AbstractMarkupFilter` that makes `<input type="submit"/>` autolinks:

```
markupSettings.setMarkupParserFactory(new IMarkupParserFactory() {
    public MarkupParser newMarkupParser(MarkupResourceStream resource) {
        final MarkupParser parser = new MarkupParser(new XmlPullParser(), resource);
        parser.appendMarkupFilter(new AbstractMarkupFilter() {
            public MarkupElement nextTag() throws ParseException {
                final ComponentTag tag = (ComponentTag)getParent().nextTag();
                if (tag == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                if (tag.getId() != null) {
                    return tag;
                }

                if (!tag.isOpen() && !tag.isOpenClose()) {
                    return tag;
                }

                if (tag.getName().equals("input") && !(tag instanceof WicketTag)) {
                    final String type = tag.getAttributes().getString("type");
                    if ("submit".equals(type)) {
                        tag.enableAutolink(true);
                        tag.setId(WicketLinkTagHandler.AUTOLINK_ID);
                        tag.setAutoComponentTag(true);
                        tag.setModified(true);
                    }
                }
                return tag;
            }
        };
        return parser;
    }
});
```

Then I install an `IComponentResolver` before the existing `AutoLinkResolver`:

```
final List<IComponentResolver> componentResolvers = getPageSettings().getComponentResolvers();
for (int i ; i < componentResolvers.size(); i++) {
    final IComponentResolver resolver = componentResolvers.get(i);
    if (resolver instanceof AutoLinkResolver) {
        componentResolvers.add(i, new IComponentResolver() {
            @Override
            public boolean resolve(MarkupContainer container, MarkupStream markupStream, ComponentTag tag) {
                if (tag.isAutolinkEnabled()) {
                    if (tag.getName().equals("input")) {
                        final String type = tag.getAttribute("type");
                        if ("submit".equals(type)) {
                            final Page page = container.getPage();
                            final String autoId = WicketLinkTagHandler.AUTOLINK_ID + Integer.toString(page.getAutoIndex());
                            if (tag.getId() == null) {
                                tag.setId(autoId);
                                tag.setAutoComponentTag(true);
                            }
                            container.autoAdd(new Button(autoId));
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
        break;
    }
}
```